# gdalinfo --formats return different values in python3 than in OSGeo4W

Tags: gdal, osgeo4w, python-3, anaconda

I am working whit geopdf to obtain the layers. When I use `driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('PDF')` it return *None*, and obviously I can't open it.

I have checked with the command `gdalinfo --formats` and it is the result in OSGeo4W
[image]

and this another when I use python 3.6 whit anaconda prompt
[image]

someone know why is completely different?
I have downloaded gdal from anaconda.

Comment: Do you mean that you may be using two different GDAL binaries? Drivers to be included are selected when GDAL is compiled.

Comment: I mean that, yes, I have 2 differents gdal install one in Osgeo4W and another in python, I have cheked and the version are different, must be that is the problem... is posible conected the Osgeo4w gdal version whit python 3.6? thanks

Comment: Why don't you run Python from OSGeo4W Shell? The py3_env.bat sets the environment for Python 3.

Comment: how can I do that?, because I need create an script, not execute that from the shell. thanks